# How to define a variable in the suite config file in FitNesse

Tags: fitnesse

how to define a variable in FitNesse´ suite config file which then can be used within the FitNesse tests?
I´m looking for an equivalent to define a variable via `!define MY_VAR {some value}`

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by Mike Stockdale and Markus Gaertner:

FitNesse wiki variables can be defined:

- With !define on the current page
- With !define on any ancestor page
- In the system.properties file
- As environment variables
- As a -D argument at the command line.

Taking that list to the next step, I would ask:

- why do you want these values in a suite config file?
- What do you mean by a suite config file?
- What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Thx for the answer.
To answer your questions:
- I want to define all the variables that are used in more then one test in one central place.
- Depending on the environment I execute the tests in, these variables have different values, therefor I want to be able to change them from the outside of FitNesse (e.g. by the build tool).
- For more info about suite config files, pls check here: http://syterra.com/FitnesseDotNet/SuiteConfigurationFile.html

Thx

Comment: It doesn't appear from looking at the FitSharp documentation and a quick dive into the code that this is possible right now.  That said, I'm not a fitSharp guy, so it might be that I'm missing something.

The best option I could recommend then is a batch file that sets environment variables for all of the stuff you want to configure.  There might even be a way to inject environment variables in to the launch environment from the build tool (I know Hudson does this).  Any environment variable would be available in all pages.

Comment: fitSharp can't define FitNesse wiki variables because it doesn't get invoked until after FitNesse has rendered the HTML.  Environment variables is probably the way to go.